# NSAttributedString bullet list issues

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am trying to create a bullet list using `NSAttributedString` and `UITextView`. And, here is what I was able to achieve so far:[image]

As one can see, there is a small "shift" between two lines. Here is a fragment of code which I use to build attributed string:

```
func add(bulletList strings: [String],
         indentation: CGFloat = 15,
         lineSpacing: CGFloat = 3,
         paragraphSpacing: CGFloat = 10) {

    func createParagraphAttirbute() -> NSParagraphStyle {
        var paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle
        let nonOptions = NSDictionary() as! [NSTextTab.OptionKey: Any]

        paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
        paragraphStyle.tabStops = [
            NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: indentation, options: nonOptions)]
        paragraphStyle.defaultTabInterval = indentation
        paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = paragraphSpacing
        paragraphStyle.headIndent = indentation
        return paragraphStyle
    }

    var buffer = NSMutableAttributedString.init()

    for string in strings {
        let formattedString = "\u{2022} \(string)\n"
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: formattedString)
        let paragraphStyle = createParagraphAttirbute()

        attributedString.addAttributes(
            [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle],
            range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        attributedString.addAttributes(
            textAttributes,
            range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        let string:NSString = NSString(string: formattedString)
        let rangeForBullet:NSRange = string.range(of: bulletPoint)
        attributedString.addAttributes(bulletAttirbutes, range: rangeForBullet)
        buffer.append(attributedString)
    }
}
```

Do you think something is wrong with selected paragraph parameters? Because the code does almost what is expected, excluding this gap.

### Update 1

Following @the4kman advice, I've changed provided code like this:

```
paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = indentation
```

But now I have all lines aligned with each other, including the bullet point:

[image]

### Update 2

Ok, the solution was quite simple - replace space with tab. See updated code below.

Comment: Provide here values for `textAttributes, bulletPoint, bulletAttirbutes`, as they found invalid/unknown, when I tried your code. So I can see/test full code.

Comment: @Krunal Thank you for response, have already found the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@the4kman, @Krunal, Thank you for your responses! The solution was even more simple. Replacing space symbol with `\t` in `let formattedString = "\u{2022} \(string)\n` gives you valid indentation.

For completeness, the full solution code is (just replacing one char):

```
func add(bulletList strings: [String],
         font: UIFont,
         indentation: CGFloat = 15,
         lineSpacing: CGFloat = 3,
         paragraphSpacing: CGFloat = 10,
         textColor: UIColor = .black,
         bulletColor: UIColor = .red) -> NSAttributedString {

    func createParagraphAttirbute() -> NSParagraphStyle {
        var paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle
        let nonOptions = NSDictionary() as! [NSTextTab.OptionKey: Any]

        paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
        paragraphStyle.tabStops = [
            NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: indentation, options: nonOptions)]
        paragraphStyle.defaultTabInterval = indentation
        paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = paragraphSpacing
        paragraphStyle.headIndent = indentation
        return paragraphStyle
    }

    let bulletPoint = "\u{2022}"
    let textAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: font, .foregroundColor: textColor]
    let bulletAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: font, .foregroundColor: bulletColor]
    let buffer = NSMutableAttributedString.init()

    for string in strings {
        let formattedString = "\(bulletPoint)\t\(string)\n"
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: formattedString)
        let paragraphStyle = createParagraphAttirbute()

        attributedString.addAttributes(
            [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle],
            range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        attributedString.addAttributes(
            textAttributes,
            range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        let string:NSString = NSString(string: formattedString)
        let rangeForBullet:NSRange = string.range(of: bulletPoint)
        attributedString.addAttributes(bulletAttributes, range: rangeForBullet)
        buffer.append(attributedString)
    }

    return buffer
}
```

Comment: Pl. provide a full working code here, add missing info, that I mentioned with my comment, to make this answer more effective and useful.

Comment: @Krunal Sorry, the code fragment was extracted from the class. Now it should work as a standalone function.

Comment: it shows me `buffer` is missing only. Can you add info about buffer also. I think it's an array of string right?

Comment: @Krunal Ah, a lot of missing variables, colors also. Now should be fine.

Comment: How can we remove the bullet list ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Objective-C snippet, based mostly on the accepted answer:

```
NSString* text = 
            "•\tSome text for bullet 1.\n"
            "•\tSome text for bullet 2.\n"
            "•\tSome text for bullet 3."

UIFont* bodyFont = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle: UIFontTextStyleBody];
CGFloat indentSize = bodyFont.pointSize;
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paraStyle = [[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paraStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
paraStyle.tabStops = @[ [[[NSTextTab alloc] initWithTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft location:indentSize options:@{}] ];
paraStyle.defaultTabInterval = indentSize;
paraStyle.headIndent = indentSize;
paraStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0;
paraStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0.85;
paraStyle.lineSpacing = 0;
paraStyle.paragraphSpacing = bodyFont.lineHeight * 0.25;
paraStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 0;
[atrStr appendAttributedString:
 [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:avc.message attributes:@{
      NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paraStyle,
      NSFontAttributeName: bodyFont,
  }]];
```