# show bullets in label on tableview cell swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uilabel

[image: image is attached for reference]

I have a table view, inside the table view I have multiple cells as shows in attached image.
I want to show amenities items like : air conditioning, swimming pool, gym, tv cable etc like bullets.

How can I achieve this

I have all these value in my model coming from API response.

```
          let ac = "Air Conditioning"
          let tv = "TV Cable"
          let washing = "Washing Machine"
          let connectivity = "Wi-Fi"
          let gym = "Gym"
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to add the bullet symbol? right

Comment: @udi yes.. right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good case for stack views...

- Vertical `UIStackView`
- Each "row" is a Horizontal `UIStackView` with **Distribution: Fill Equally**

Looks like this - showing Bounds Rectangles:

[image]

without the Bounds Rectangles:

[image]

view hierarchy:

[image]

---

**Edit**

A second approach (which you may find easier)...

Use a single horizontal stack view with a single label on each "side" and use `.attributedText`.

Set the `.attributedText` of each label to a formatted, bulleted attributed string.

The cell prototype could look like this:

[image]

Then, use this code (slightly modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46889728/6257435) to generate a formatted, bulleted attributed string:

```
func add(bulletList strings: [String],
         font: UIFont,
         indentation: CGFloat = 15,
         lineSpacing: CGFloat = 3,
         paragraphSpacing: CGFloat = 10,
         textColor: UIColor = .black,
         bulletColor: UIColor = .red) -> NSAttributedString {
    
    func createParagraphAttirbute() -> NSParagraphStyle {
        var paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle
        let nonOptions = NSDictionary() as! [NSTextTab.OptionKey: Any]
        
        paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
        paragraphStyle.tabStops = [
            NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: indentation, options: nonOptions)]
        paragraphStyle.defaultTabInterval = indentation
        paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = paragraphSpacing
        paragraphStyle.headIndent = indentation
        return paragraphStyle
    }
    
    let bulletPoint = "\u{2022}"
    let textAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: font, .foregroundColor: textColor]
    let bulletAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: font, .foregroundColor: bulletColor]
    let buffer = NSMutableAttributedString.init()
    
    for string in strings {
        var formattedString = "\(bulletPoint)\t\(string)"

        // don't add newLine if it's the last bullet
        if string != strings.last {
            formattedString += "\n"
        }

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: formattedString)
        let paragraphStyle = createParagraphAttirbute()
        
        attributedString.addAttributes(
            [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle],
            range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
        
        attributedString.addAttributes(
            textAttributes,
            range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
        
        let string:NSString = NSString(string: formattedString)
        let rangeForBullet:NSRange = string.range(of: bulletPoint)
        attributedString.addAttributes(bulletAttributes, range: rangeForBullet)
        buffer.append(attributedString)
    }
    
    return buffer
}
```

A quick implementation of that using your image as sample data results in this:

[image]